# How to view pdf using QT framework on blackberry playbook

Tags: qt, pdf, blackberry-playbook, native-code

I had asked before also for rendering pdf but its in blackberry JAVA development.
But currently I want to know , is it possible to render a PDF in the playbook using native sdk 2.0.0 with the QT framework.
If it is possible then can you suggest me some example if it exist on the google?
Is it possible with any third party library i.e of c++??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, provided you agree to the licensing of the third party library.

Open source world has two know libraries for PDF rendering:

1. [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)
2. [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/)

Both provide bindings for Qt, the bad part is that both are licensed GPL.

However, the firms working behind both libraries provide commercial licensing options.
For commercial licensing:
[GlyphandCog](http://www.glyphandcog.com/XpdfWidgetQt.html) provides commercial licensing for XpdfWidget/Qt
[Artifex Software, Inc.](http://www.artifex.com/) provides commercial licensing for MuPDF.